# JQuery not working in Squarespace blog.item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, squarespace, affix

Working on blog.item in Squarespace Marquee

Using Affix from Twitter Bootstrap for blog posts, simple plug-in to keep the blog title ( on the left ) *position: fixed;* until it hits the top of the comments section, then switch to *position: absolute;*

Should be simple, but I can't get this to fire when it hits the top of the comments section. Errors every time.

When I opened up my console to debug, I can't find a single element on the page other than the body. This is obviously the issue, but I'm stumped.

Every element on the page returns "null" based on class or ID, even though it's 100% within the HTML of the page - I'm copying and pasting from my inspector.

```
ALL CONSOLE ACTIONS OTHER THAN $('body')

$('#comments')
null
```

[THIS](https://diane-abapo.squarespace.com/blog/2015/01/fashion-cookie-photographed-lloyd-pursall-london) is the page I'm working on.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I seem to be getting the $('#comments') and its element.

Comment: I have just run a couple of commands in the console and jquery is firing correctly. http://oi62.tinypic.com/2k2078.jpg

Comment: And $('#comments'); worked for me in the console.

Comment: It also looks like you are calling two versions of jquery on two separate calls: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! All up and running smoothly now, it was indeed a script tag issue.

Here's my final code:

```
    $( function() {

      $( '#myaffix' ).affix({

        offset : {

          bottom : function () {

            return ( document.body.clientHeight - $( '#comments-outer-wrapper' )[ 0 ].offsetTop );

          }

        }

      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Have you called in the jquery using this?